# How to make this code tail-recursive?

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

Suppose I have this function, in pseudo-code, that reverse a list:

```
def function reverse( list ) :
if ( empty(list) ) 
    return empty_list;
else 
    return append( 
        reverse( list(2, lenght) , 
                 list(1)));
```

This code is not tail-recursive; 
how can i make it tail-recursive?

Comment: No, it's not a homework (otherwise i had tagged it as homework); i'm just not sure about what tail recursion is and i would like to see it on an example. It's not a real language, a pseudo-language I invented on the fly to ask this question..

Comment: [Tail Recursion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See: [Tail Call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

For [F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-fsharp.aspx)

```
let map f l =
    let rec loop acc = function
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | x::xs -> loop (f x::acc) xs
    loop [] l
```

For [reversing a string](http://codemonkeyism.com/string-reversing-part-ii-tail-recursion/)